How Can I Summarize A Table With Location Information And Label Counts In Columns in Excel
I have a table that has information for locations. The locations are have both address and country info. The labels are listed in order by count, and not all locations are listed for each location. A sample table is attached. The real table has 73 countries, and 40 labels.
For simplicity, this is a sample table with 3 countries and 4 labels:
This is how my table is structured:

This is the output I would like:


Assuming there is no Excel Constraints as per the tags posted, then one could use one of the followings :


• Formula used in cell J1
=LET(
     _ForRept, UNIQUE(HSTACK(B2:B11,COUNTIF(B2:B11,B2:B11)*(COLUMNS(C2:H11)/2))),
     _Country, TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(,SUM(TAKE(_ForRept,,-1)))<=TAKE(_ForRept,,-1), TAKE(_ForRept,,1)),2),
     _Data, HSTACK(_Country, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(C2:H11),2)),
     VSTACK({"Country","Label","Total"},GROUPBY(TAKE(_Data,,2), TAKE(_Data,,-1),SUM,,0,-1)))


Or Using BYROW()
=LET(
     _ForRept, UNIQUE(HSTACK(B2:B11,COUNTIF(B2:B11,B2:B11)*(COLUMNS(C2:H11)/2))),
     _Country, TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(,SUM(TAKE(_ForRept,,-1)))<=TAKE(_ForRept,,-1), TAKE(_ForRept,,1)),2),
     _Data, HSTACK(_Country, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(C2:H11),2)),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(TAKE(_Data,,2)),
     VSTACK({"Country","Label","Total"},HSTACK(_Uniq, BYROW(TAKE(_Uniq,,1)&"|"&TAKE(_Uniq,,-1),LAMBDA(x, 
     SUM((x=INDEX(_Data,,1)&"|"&INDEX(_Data,,2))*TAKE(_Data,,-1)))))))


Another method using REDUCE()
=REDUCE({"Country","Label","Sum"},UNIQUE(B2:B11),LAMBDA(α,δ,
 LET(φ,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(FILTER(C2:H11,B2:B11=δ)),2),ε,TAKE(φ,,1),
 Θ,UNIQUE(ε),VSTACK(α,IFNA(HSTACK(δ,Θ,
 BYROW(TRANSPOSE((TOROW(Θ)=ε)*TAKE(φ,,-1)),LAMBDA(Σ,SUM(Σ)))),δ)))))



You should use Power Query (PQ) inside Excel for this. There are many benefits to use PQ including once you finish the transformation then if data is added to the top table a week later you can hit the refresh buttons and it calculates the output table again.

Example of PQ splitting values
Example of PQ scraping the
web, you can also scrape lots of other files.
This is a video
something really similar to your problem unpivot paired data


Alternatively you can use SUMPRODUCT with all legacy versions of Excel.
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$11=A15)*($C$2:$G$11=B15),$D$2:$H$11)   


